# Chaining functions that return deferred objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have some functions that return jQuery Deferred objects and I'm having trouble getting my head around chaining them and processing the results.

Consider the following example:

```js
const start = Date.now();

// Print a message with a timestamp.
function log (v) {
    console.log(`${Date.now() - start} ${v}`);
}

// Return a deferred function that resolves 1 second later with 'value'.
function test (value) {
    log(`test(${value})`);
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            log(`resolve(${value})`);
            def.resolve(value);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

// Example:
test(42)
    .then(function (v) { log(v); })
    .then(test(99))
    .then(function (v) { log(v); })
    .then(function () { log('done'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is *supposed* to run `test(42)`, then do something with its results, then run `test(99)` then do something with those results, all in order. However, it actually outputs (first number is ms since program started):

```
0 test(42)
0 test(99)
1003 resolve(42)
1003 42
1003 undefined    <-- supposed to be 99
1005 done
1005 resolve(99)
```

So both of the `test`s get called at the same time right at the start, and everything else is off. What I *want* it to output is something like:

```
0 test(42)
1000 resolve(42)
1000 42
1000 test(99)
2000 resolve(99)
2000 99
2000 done
```

How can I make this work? I tried returning `$.Deferred(...).promise()`, with no change in behavior, and I also tried using `done` instead of `then` but the only change was it printed `42` a second time instead of `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each deferred only resolves once.  For each deferred chain, you have to attach them correctly.  Also the second call to test needs to be in a function so that it does not execute immediately.

```js
const start = Date.now();

// Print a message with a timestamp.
function log (v) {
    console.log(`${Date.now() - start} ${v}`);
}

// Return a deferred function that resolves 1 second later with 'value'.
function test (value) {
    log(`test(${value})`);
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            log(`resolve(${value})`);
            def.resolve(value);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

// Example:
test(42)
    .then(function (v) { log(v); })
    .then(function () {
        test(99)
           .then(function (v) { log(v); })
           .then(function () { log('done'); });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. And nesting them like this is the only way to do it? So if I'm, say, building a long chain with a for loop or something I have to either write some helper function to do them sequentially, or finesse everything into this nested form?

Comment: Once a deferred resolves, it will execute all then() attached to it, regardless of if one contains another deferred or not.  So you have to chain your logic with that in mind.

Comment: Btw, I did a little experiment playing with your advice, it actually *appears* to work correctly if I *just* make the second call to test be a function (that returns that deferred object), even without the nesting, [like this](https://pastebin.com/r5Eda5Zp). Maybe if the `then` handler returns something thenable, it changes what the rest of the chain is operating on?

Comment: Can you share a link to your experiment?

Comment: Huh, interesting.